# How to set custom android app notification icon when notification in send from webpage

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

android application receives notification properly, but it shows white square box for notification icon.
I want to set proper notification icon.
here is my c# code, I want to send notification from webpage button click to android application.

```
     public string SendPushNotification(string deviceId)
            {
                string response;

                try
                {

                    string serverKey = "AAAAu0:******cw"; // Something very long
                    string senderId = "1:******";

                    // Also something very long, 
                    // got from android
                    // string deviceId = "//topics/all";             // Use this to notify all devices, 
                    // but App must be subscribed to 
                    // topic notification
                    WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

                    tRequest.Method = "post";
                    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    var data = new
                    {
                        to = deviceId,
                        notification = new
                        {
                            body = "Greetings",
                            title = "Augsburg",
                            sound = "Enabled"


                        }
                    };

                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
                    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
                    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                    using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                        {
                            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                                {
                                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                    response = sResponseFromServer;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response = ex.Message;
                }

                return response;
            }


            public string all()
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT distinct token FROM tbl_user";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                string token = "";
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    string response = SendPushNotification(dr["token"].ToString());

                }

                con.Close();

                return token;


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in the manifest file-

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/notification_icon" />
```